# subset of a separable space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Normed Linear Space.If $X$ is separable and $A$ is a subset of $X$, then show that $A$ is separable.

Proof: since $X$ is separable it has a countable dense subset say $(x_n):n\in \mathbb N$. Suppose  let $a\in A$ then $a\in X$ and hence there exist a point $x_m$ such that $||x_m-a||<\epsilon$.

Thus choose all such that $x_n$ from the countable set and hence $A$ becomes separable. Is the justification correct?

Can anyone please suggest required edits if needed.

Comment: One has to find a dense countable subset in $A$.

Comment: then what will be the modification

Comment: @PeterFranek But here we have a normed space, which is a metric space. In this case a subset is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $(x_n)$ be a dense countable subset of $X$. Consider open balls
$$ B(x_n,\tfrac{1}{m})=\{ x\in X; \|x-x_n\|<\tfrac{1}{m}\}\qquad m, n \in {\mathbb N}. $$
If $B(x_n,\tfrac{1}{m})\cap A\ne \emptyset$, then choose an element $a_{n,m}$ from this intersection. Hence $(a_{n,m})$ is a countable subset of $A$. Show that it is dense in $A$.

Comment: if intersection is empty forall n?

Comment: Cannot be because $(x_n)$ is dense in $X$ and $A$ is a subset of $X$.